# C++11(14/17/20) Thread Management

Tags: c++, c++11, multithreading

I'm implementing something of a thread janitor in modern C++. What I've got works, and while it's not organized in the way I'd like yet, I'd like some feedback on the fundamentals. Thank you in advance for any and all pointers. =)

All of the threads (including `main()` in order to signal program end) share data via this:

```
#ifndef SHAREDDATA_HPP
#define SHAREDDATA_HPP

#include <condition_variable>
#include <thread>

class SharedData {
    public:
        std::mutex              keypress_mutex;
        std::condition_variable keypress_cv;
        bool                    keypress_flag;

        std::mutex              thread_count_mutex;
        std::condition_variable thread_count_cv;
        unsigned int            thread_count;

        std::mutex              thread_kill_mutex;
        std::condition_variable thread_kill_cv;
        bool                    thread_kill_flag;

        SharedData():
            keypress_flag{false},
            thread_count{0},
            thread_kill_flag{false}
        { }
        ~SharedData() = default;
};

#endif // SHAREDDATA_HPP
```

Then we've got a little RAII guy to help keep track of thread count:

```
#ifndef THREADCOUNTER_HPP
#define THREADCOUNTER_HPP

#include <thread>

class SharedData;

class ThreadCounter {
    public:
        explicit ThreadCounter(SharedData *share);
        ~ThreadCounter();
    private:
        SharedData         *_share;
};

#endif // THREADCOUNTER_HPP


//--------------------------


#include "ThreadCounter.hpp"

#include "SharedData.hpp"

ThreadCounter::ThreadCounter(SharedData *share) :
    _share{share}
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> _lock(_share->thread_count_mutex);
    share->thread_count++;
}

ThreadCounter::~ThreadCounter() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> _lock(_share->thread_count_mutex);
    _share->thread_count--;

    if(_share->thread_count == 0) {
        _share->thread_count_cv.notify_one();
    }
}
```

Next, the `ManagedThread` class itself:

```
#ifndef MANAGEDTHREAD_HPP
#define MANAGEDTHREAD_HPP

#include <thread>

class SharedData;

class ManagedThread {
    public:
        void launch();

        explicit ManagedThread(SharedData *share);
        ~ManagedThread();
        ManagedThread() = delete;

        void operator()();

    private:
        SharedData *_share;
        std::thread _thread;
};

#endif // MANAGEDTHREAD_HPP


//--------------------------


#include "ManagedThread.hpp"

#include "SharedData.hpp"
#include "ThreadCounter.hpp"

#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

void ManagedThread::launch() {
    if(!_thread.joinable()) {
        _thread = std::thread(std::ref(*this));
    }
    else {
        assert((false) && "Managed Thread not launchable!");
    }
}

ManagedThread::ManagedThread(SharedData *share) :
    _share{share},
    _thread{std::thread()}
{ }

ManagedThread::~ManagedThread() {
    if(_thread.joinable()) {
        _thread.join();
    }
}

void ManagedThread::operator()() {
    ThreadCounter tc(_share);
    while(true) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(250ms);
        std::cout << "Whee!" << std::endl;

        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> kill_lock(_share->thread_kill_mutex);
        if(_share->thread_kill_cv.wait_for(kill_lock, 100ms,
                [&](){ return _share->thread_kill_flag; })) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

And `ThreadManager` who does the cleanup coordination:

```
#ifndef THREADMANAGER_HPP
#define THREADMANAGER_HPP

class SharedData;

class ThreadManager {
    public:
        explicit ThreadManager(SharedData *share) : _share{share} { };
        ~ThreadManager() = default;

        void operator()();

    private:
        SharedData *_share;
};

#endif // THREADMANAGER_HPP


//--------------------------

#include "ThreadManager.hpp"

#include "SharedData.hpp"

#include <chrono>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

void ThreadManager::operator()() {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(25ms);

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> keypress_lock(_share->keypress_mutex);
    _share->keypress_cv.wait(keypress_lock,
                            [&](){ return _share->keypress_flag; });
    keypress_lock.unlock();

    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> kill_lock(_share->thread_kill_mutex);
        _share->thread_kill_flag = true;
    }
    _share->thread_kill_cv.notify_all();

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> count_lock(_share->thread_count_mutex);
    _share->thread_count_cv.wait(count_lock,
                                [&](){ return _share->thread_count == 0; });
}
```

And, finally, a `main.cpp` to tie it all together.

```
#include "SharedData.hpp"
#include "ThreadManager.hpp"
#include "ManagedThread.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <future>

int main() {
    SharedData share;
    ThreadManager tm(&share);
    ManagedThread t0(&share);

    t0.launch();

    std::future<void> cf = std::async(std::launch::async, std::move(tm));

    int input;
    std::cin >> input;
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(share.keypress_mutex);
        share.keypress_flag = true;
    }
    share.keypress_cv.notify_one();
    cf.get();

    return 0;
}
```

What I know I don't really like is that `ThreadManager` doesn't own `SharedData`. I'd also like `ThreadManager` to generically manage any `ManagedThread` and perhaps overload `operator()` in an inherited thread of some sort so callable can do anything but still be "managed".

At this point, those are just musings, though - what I'd really like to know is how well or poorly the system has been implemented thus far. =)

Again, thanks for your feedback; I look forward to improving this setup and utilizing it in future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Thread management in C++20

In C++20 (which you mention in the title of the question), there is [`std::jthread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/jthread) which basically does most of what you are doing in your classes: it handles joining a thread in its destructor, and there is a way to request a thread to stop what it is doing, which is also automatically called in the destructor. Your example could be rewritten like so in C++20:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

int main() {
    std::jthread whee([](std::stop_token stoken){
        while (!stoken.stop_requested()) {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(250ms);
            std::cout << "Whee!\n";
        }
    });

    int input;
    std::cin >> input;

    // Unnecessary since the thread object is destroyed anyway:
    whee.request_stop();
}
```

If you have multiple `std::jthreads` and you want them all to stop at the same time, just let all the thread objects go out of scope simultaneously, or put them in a container that can be [`clear()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/clear)ed. For example:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<std::jthread> threads;
    
    for (auto i: {1, 2, 3}) {
         threads.emplace_back([i](std::stop_token stoken){
            while (!stoken.stop_requested()) {
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(250ms);
                std::cout << "Whee " << i << "!\n";
            }
         });
    }

    int input;
    std::cin >> input;

    std::cout << "Stopping all threads...\n";
    threads.clear();
    std::cout << "Done.\n";
}
```

Basically, `std::vector<std::jthread>` replaces your whole thread manager.

## Sharing state amonst threads

Your idea to have some shared state that indicates whether threads should stop has merit. You only need to update one variable to send a signal to all of them, whereas with the `std::jthread` solution I mentioned, each `std::jthread` object has its own stop token. As upkajdt mentioned in his answer though, you can simplify things a lot by just using a `std::atomic<bool>` as a flag. In his answer, he declared this as a global variable. In case you don't want or can't use a global variable, and you want some state shared amongst multiple threads, then indeed you want to manage this state in a thread-safe way. Most importantly, it shouldn't be destroyed before every thread using it is done with it. This is a large part of what your code tries to do. However, there is already functionality in the standard library that allows you to do this: [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr). Your code could be rewritten like so:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

int main() {
    auto kill_flag = std::make_shared<std::atomic<bool>>(false);

    std::thread whee([kill_flag](){
        while (!*kill_flag) {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(250ms);
            std::cout << "Whee!\n";
        }
    });

    int input;
    std::cin >> input;

    *kill_flag = true;
    whee.join();
}
```

Here the `kill_flag` is passed *by value* to the thread. This uses the copy-constructor of `std::shared_ptr`, which will increase the reference count of the atomic bool, and once the thread stops it will call the destructor of its copy of `kill_flag`, which will in turn decrease the reference count. So this replaces your `ThreadCounter`.

Comment: Good and detailed review as always! I wasn’t even aware of the existence of `std::jthread`, actually two weeks back I did not know about `std::string_view`. Do you have any recommendations on how to stay up to date with all the developments while still having time to do your day job?

Comment: @upkajdt [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/) is a great resource. At the top of that page it lists the versions of the C++ standard, you can click on them and get a page that describes what is new in that standard. There's also one for C++23, which is a work in progress of course, but check it now and then to know what's going to come. Also great is to follow talks from [C++ conferences](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/conferences-worldwide). There are also various [YouTube channels](https://www.youtube.com/user/lefticus1), [blogs](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/) and so on.

Comment: A shared pointer seems unnecessary just for the purpose of having a thread-safe “done” flag. All you need to do is put the flag in the same place as whatever is managing the threads, and pass it by reference; so long as it’s constructed first, it will outlast the threads. Or, for a more complicated setup, instead of a shared pointer to a plain atomic `bool`, use a `std::stop_source` and get `std::stop_token`s from that to pass to each thread function.

Comment: @indi Yes, in the above example it is unnecessary, but if threads are created and signalled from various functions with less well-determined lifetimes it migh be necessary. Also, `std::stop_source` is C++20, if you cannot use that yet then I think the atomic `bool` is a reasonable equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

## Pass arguments by reference

You are passing `SharedData` by a pointer. It would have been much cleaner to pass it by reference:

```cpp
class ThreadCounter {
public:
    explicit ThreadCounter(SharedData& share);
    ~ThreadCounter();
private:
    SharedData& _share;
};
```

## Use atomic variables instead of `lock`.

Locking is costly and overly complicated when you could have simply used atomic variables:

```cpp
struct SharedData
{
    std::atomic<bool> keypress_flag = false;
}

int main() {
    SharedData share;
    // start threads
    int input;
    std::cin >> input;
    share.keypress_flag = true;
    // join threads
}
```

## Don't use std::endl

`std::endl` Flushes the output. You don't have to, simply use `\n`:

```cpp
std::cout << "Whee!\n";
```

## Final thoughts

I'm not really sure what you are trying to accomplish. It seems to me that you could have replaced all your code with something as simple as the following:

```cpp
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

std::atomic_bool running = true;

void func()
{
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    while (running)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(250ms);
        std::cout << "Whee!\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::thread thread(func);
    int input;
    std::cin >> input;
    running = false;
    thread.join();
}
```